# 2nd ddl is not filling properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

---

I changed the view code but it still doesn't fill the fund ddl. Can anyone see what the problem is?

---

This code does call ClientInvestmentsSince2 via Json, that method in the report controller code executes completely. Then when control returns to the view, I'm not sure what happens. The code responds to a select item of the clients ddl and is supposed to fill the fund ddl with the funds that the selected client holds. Something is fishy... the alerts are not all firing after I select the client. **alert("here2")** is but not **alert("here3")** or **alert("here4")**.

Can you help? Thanks.

**************************** here's the view code ***************************************

```
@model StockHoldings.Models.Investments

<head>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    @*<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>*@
</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    @Html.DropDownList("Client", ViewData["client"] as SelectList, "Select Client", new { id = "Client_ID", style = "width: 150px;" })<br />
    @*{ @Html.DropDownList("Fund", "Select Fund")};*@
        <select id="Fund" name="Fund" , style="width: 150px;"></select><br />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PurchaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('#Client_ID').change(function ()
        {
            alert('here');

            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id: $('#Client_ID').val() }, function (data)
            {
                var items = '<option>Select Fund</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, Fund)
                {
                    items += "<option value='" + Fund.i + "'>" + Fund.val + "</option>";
                })
                .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorMessage) { alert(errorMessage); });

                //assign the result to the Fund selectlist
                $('#Fund').html(items);
            });
            alert('here2');
        });
        alert('here3');
    });
```

*************************************** here's the ReportController code *********************************

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StockHoldings.Controllers
{
    public class ReportsController : Controller
    {

        // GET: Reports/ClientInvestmentsSince
        public ActionResult ClientInvestmentsSince()
        {
            string str = @"Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HoldingsConnectionString2;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string query = "select ID, LastName from Clients";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr[1].ToString(), Value = rdr[0].ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["client"] = li;

            return View();
        }


        public JsonResult ClientInvestmentsSince2(int Id)
        {
            string str = @"Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HoldingsConnectionString2;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string query = "select ID, Fund from Investments where Client_ID = " + Id;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = rdr["ID"].ToString(), Value = rdr["Fund"].ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["Fund"] = li;

*********************************************

// ViewData["Fund"] is loading correctly, and there is a clean exit of the method.


            return Json(li, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#Client_ID').change(function () {
             alert('here');

             $.getJSON('@Url.Action("ClientInvestmentsSince2", "Reports")', { id: $('#Client_ID').val() }, function (data) {
                 //On client DDL change you  have to fill second drop down list right so after called a method it willl
                 //return json here and you can then play with that json to fill your second DDL
             });
             alert('here2'); // it will fire when Client ddl change
         });
         alert('here3');// it will fire once when there is page load
       });
        alert('here4');//it will never fire as it's not in ready function
```

Please find my comments on your script there were some syntax errors i have resolved and some useful comments to understand how this function works hope it helps